# Unable to verify expectations in a ruby class

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

I have a Class definition as below:

```
def initialize(driver)
    @driver = driver
end

def verify_page(username)
    wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
    btnSettings = wait.until { @driver.find_element(:xpath => "//a[@href='/UserManagement/MyAccount']") }
    expect(btnSettings.text).to eq('Portal Administrator' + ' -- ' + username)
  end
end
```

When I run the code that calls the 'verify' method of this class, I get the error:

```
undefined method `expect' for #<PortalHomePage:0x00000003b1d188>
```

How do i get past this problem?

Comment: You're using `rspec`?  Are you requiring it correctly?

Comment: I have the line **require 'rspec/expectations'** in my env.rb file. Is that sufficient or should I be doing something else?

Comment: Hmmm...perhaps you should post your env.rb file.  Even better, try to provide the minimal but complete amount of code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use rspec expectations.

Please do the following in your env.rb file

```
require 'rspec'
include RSpec::Matchers
```

This will solve your current problem

Comment for more information.

Hope it helps!!